# Flutter Bloc implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am new to flutter and flutter bloc. I am trying to prepare an example, where i have a bulb and a switch on the screen. My idea is to glow the buld when i press the switch and put it off when i press the switch again. I have two images each for buld and switch on/off. My code doesnt work, dont know where i am getting it wrong. Here is my code

Main,dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'blocs/bulb/bulb_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => BulbBloc(),
            child: BlocBuilder<BulbBloc, BulbState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                String bulbImgSrc = state.isOn
                    ? 'assets/images/turned-on.png'
                    : 'assets/images/turned-off.png';
                String switchImgSrc = state.isOn
                    ? 'assets/images/switch-on.png'
                    : 'assets/images/switch-off.png';
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(bulbImgSrc),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print('Tapped');
                        state.isOn
                            ? context.read<BulbBloc>().add(BulbOnEvent())
                            : context.read<BulbBloc>().add(BulbOffEvent());
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(switchImgSrc),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bulb_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'bulb_event.dart';

part 'bulb_state.dart';

class BulbBloc extends Bloc<BulbEvent, BulbState> {
  BulbBloc() : super(BulbState.initial()) {
    on<BulbOffEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(const BulbState(false));
    });
    on<BulbOnEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(const BulbState(true));
    });
  }
}
```

bulb_state.dart

```
part of 'bulb_bloc.dart';

class BulbState extends Equatable {
  final bool isOn;

  const BulbState(this.isOn);

  factory BulbState.initial() => const BulbState(false);

  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [isOn];
}
```

bulb_event.dart

```
part of 'bulb_bloc.dart';

class BulbEvent extends Equatable {
  const BulbEvent();

  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class BulbOnEvent extends BulbEvent {}

class BulbOffEvent extends BulbEvent {}
```

[image]

Why the code is not functioning

Comment: What exactly isn't functioning? Do you see the "Tapped" line in the console? If you do, but nothing happens, but in more print statements (or use a debugger) to find out where it stops behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: yes i can see tapped in the console

Comment: Try my answer it working.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the light is on and they tap the switch you want to turn the light off. You had these reversed.

```
state.isOn
 ? context.read<BulbBloc>().add(BulbOffEvent()) 
 : context.read<BulbBloc>().add(BulbOnEvent());
```

Comment: You might consider just having one event named LightSwitchTapped.  That way the UI isn't having to make a decision on which event to add. The logic of whether the light is being turned on or off could be in the bloc. I like events being named to indicate what happened. Event names should typically end with "ed".

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your your gesture detector  as mentioned below

```
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print('Tapped');
                        state.isOn
                            ? BlocProvider.of<BulbBloc>(context)
                                .add(BulbOnEvent())
                            : BlocProvider.of<BulbBloc>(context)
                                .add(BulbOffEvent());
                      },
```

and bulb_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'bulb_event.dart';

part 'bulb_state.dart';

class BulbBloc extends Bloc<BulbEvent, BulbState> {
  BulbBloc() : super(BulbState.initial()) {
    on<BulbOffEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(BulbState(true));
    });
    on<BulbOnEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(BulbState(false));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can some change in you main.dart file :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => BulbBloc(),
            child: BlocBuilder<BulbBloc, BulbState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                 String bulbImgSrc = state.isOn
                ? 'assets/images/turned-on.png'
                : 'assets/images/turned-off.png';
            String switchImgSrc = state.isOn
                ? 'assets/images/switch-on.png'
                : 'assets/images/switch-off.png';
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(bulbImgSrc),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print('Tapped');
                        bool isOn = context.read<BulbBloc>().state.isOn;
                        if (isOn) {
                          context.read<BulbBloc>().add(BulbOffEvent());
                          setState(() {
                            bulbImgSrc = 'assets/images/turned-off.png';
                          });
                        } else {
                          context.read<BulbBloc>().add(BulbOnEvent());
                          setState(() {
                            bulbImgSrc = 'assets/images/turned-on.png';
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(switchImgSrc),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to combine two different state management solutions.